# How do I make these gaps?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have a box and I want to add these gaps in specific part.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Look up 'panel lines' on youtube. There are many tutorials on different way to do them depending on what you want them for

Answer (score 2):

Add bevel to touching geometry.

[image]